# How to make compiler check that 2 method arguments have the same type?

Tags: scala

Probably I am missing something fundamental here, but I was refactoring certain things in my code and on the halfway I noticed that my code compiles, where I would expect it would not.
So here is the method signature:

```
def checkUiFieldValue[T](fieldName:String, uiValue:T, expectedValue:T):Unit ={...}
```

Here is a place where it is used:

```
checkUiFieldValue("State", stateInListView(ar.name), ar.state)
```

The return type of the `stateInListView` is `ARState` class, while the type of the `ar.state` is `String`.
So question is why does it compile and does not tell me that types do not match? I caught myself with a thought that I expect that compiler would check that `uiValue` and `expectedValue` are of the same type `T` but probably my assumption is incorrect.

Or type parameter `T` in the method definition actually means that both arguments will be casted to `Any` in my case? If so then how should I properly restrict both args to have the same type at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to infer the types of the two arguments separately then use `=:=` to prove they're the same:

```
def test2[S, T](a: String, b: S, c: T)(implicit ev: S =:= T): T = ???
val x = test2("", new A, new A) // compiles
val y = test2("", new A, new B) // doesn't compile; can't prove A =:= B
```

This might be a bit strict for you though in the presence of subtyping:

```
class C extends B
val z = test2("", new B, new C) // doesn't compile; can't prove B =:= C
val w = test2[B, B]("", new B, new C) // does compile
```

Comment: That's really cool, thank you.
Though I am not able to understand the source code behind the `=:=` yet, but I will spend time on this later.

Comment: Btw, a very good explanation of the <:< (and thus =:=) can be found here:http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, the reason why that compiles is that `T` is the first common type between `stateInListView(ar.name)` and `ar.state`.

You can verify this by executing these lines:

```
class A()
class B()

def test[T](a : String, b : T, c : T) : T = ???   

val x : Any = test("ciao", new A(), new B()) // Compiles OK
val y : A = test[A]("ciao", new A(), new B()) // Does not compile: B does not work
val z : B = test[B]("ciao", new A(), new B()) // Does not compile: A does not work
```

Besides specifying `T` manually (e.g. `test[A](...)`), I can't really think of a way to avoid this behaviour....

Comment: Yes. I've changed the question subject to address my wish in a more clear way.
Looks like a simple task but I can't find a way to achieve compiler assistance yet.

Comment: And actually specifying manually does solve the problem :) Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are right with your final statement of the question. `Any` is being found to be only type that could be `T`, given that it's the first common super type of `stateInListView(ar.name)` and `ar.state`. Specifiying manually what `T` is at call time will ensure that they are the same, but it is less than ideal....

Comment: Ah ok, if that is doable in your case, that's great :)

Comment: Doable but now I am interested if there's some technique to do this in the definition of the method rather than at a call site.

Comment: Could it work with a type parameter bound? For example `def test[T <: ARState](a : String, b : T, c : T) : T = ???`